# I am getting the error : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_customer.email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Can anyone please help me solve this error? When I check out as a logged-in user and press the make payment button it clears the cart and does everything that it is supposed to. The problem is when I do the same for a guest user it does not clear the cart or register anything in the database. The payment button does nothing.

**error**

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecommerce\store\views.py", line 73, in processOrder
    customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecommerce\store\utils.py", line 66, in guestOrder
    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.create(**params), True
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\django\ecommerce\ecomm\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_customer.email
```

Here is guestOrder function in the utils.py file.

**Utils.py**

```
def guestOrder(request, data):
    print('User is not logged in...')

    print('Cookies:', request.COOKIES)
    name = data['form']['name']
    email = data['form']['email']

    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    items = cookieData['items']

    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(
        email = email
    )
    customer.name = name
    customer.save()

    order = Order.objects.create(
        customer = customer,
        complete = False,
        )
    for item in items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['product']['id'])

        OrderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            order=order,
            quantity=item['quantity'],
        )
    return customer, order
```

It is the processOrder function in views.py file.

**views.py**

```
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == float(order.get_cart_total):
        order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        order=order,
        address=data['shipping']['address'],
        city=data['shipping']['city'],
        state=data['shipping']['state'],
        zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
    )

    return JsonResponse('Payment Complete!', safe=False)
```

**checkout.html**

```
    document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        submitFormData()
    })

    function submitFormData(){
        console.log('Payment-Button Clicked')

        var userFormData = {
            'name': null,
            'email': null,
            'total':total,
        }
        var shippingInfo = {
            'address': null,
            'city': null,
            'state':null,
            'zipcode': null,
        }   
        if(shipping != 'False'){
            shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
            shippingInfo.city = form.city.value
            shippingInfo.state = form.state.value
            shippingInfo.zipcode = form.zipcode.value
        }
        if(user == 'AnonyousUser'){
            userFormData.name = form.name.value
            userFormData.email = form.email.value
        }

        var url = '/process_order/'
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'form': userFormData, 'shipping': shippingInfo})
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            alert('Transaction Complete');

            cart = {}
            document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

            window.location.href = "{% url 'store' %}"
        })
    }
```

error in **process_order**

```
JSONDecodeError at /process_order/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, it looks like you are not setting any email id for the guest user and trying to create a `Customer` object which requires a valid email id.

`email = data['form']['email']`

This must be setting `None` for email.

You can try giving a random email id or a default guest email id for the guest user as a work around.

Comment: I am entering a valid email id while filling the form before checkout but getting nothing

Comment: Does `request.body` has all the required values? especially the email? Can you validate?
How are you setting an email id in the form for a guest user?

Comment: I have added the submitFormData function in checkout.html file to this question you can check..

Comment: `if(user == 'AnonyousUser')` Is this correct? looks like a typo

Comment: Yes it worked.... 

if(user != 'AnonyousUser')

Thanks so much